# Проблема с повторением анимации в jQuery?

Tags: jquery

У меня есть код jQuery, который открывает и закрывает блок при нажатии на шапку. Проблема в том, что если много раз кликнуть по ней то блок продолжает открываться и закрываться, пока не проделает это столько раз, сколько раз ты кликнул, как исправить?
Вот код jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var flag = 0;
    $("#top_name").click(function(){
        if(flag == 0){
            $("#auth_form").slideDown(300);
            $("#auth_block").css({"border-bottom":"2px solid #ffffff"});
            flag = 1;
        } else {
            $("#auth_form").slideUp(300);
            $("#auth_block").css({"border-bottom":"none"});
            flag = 0;
        }
    });
});
```

и сам блок:

```
<div class="info_block" id="auth_block">
    <div id="top_name">Авторизация</div>
    <div id="auth_form">
        <div id="text_info">Логин</div>
        <input type="text" name="auth_login">
        <div id="text_info">Пароль</div>
        <input type="password" name="auth_pass"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="auth_sub" value="Войти">
        <a href="javascript://" id="goto_reg">Регистрация</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Никакого конфликта тут нет, изучите систему очередей. Чтобы избавиться от этого эффекта, достаточно вызывать `.stop()` в начале обработчика.

Comment: Проблема в том, что это доставляет дискомфорт!
Fike, спасибо! Ваша функция помогла!)
soledar10, я этого и не замечал, пока друзья это не заметили!)

Answer (score 2):

Ответ из комментария

---

Чтобы избавиться от этого эффекта, достаточно вызывать [.stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) в начале обработчика:

```
$("#auth_form").stop().slideDown(300);
// ...
$("#auth_form").stop().slideUp(300);
```